# How to make custom Dependency Property can be changed in real time when binding in wpf?

Tags: wpf, binding, real-time, dependency-properties

When we bind textblock.Text with the length of text of Textbox like this

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Row="0" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=txtName, Path=Text.Length}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

The Text of Textblock will change with the text of txtName in real time.
But when I define a new DependencyProperty in a WPF user control like this:

```
    //MyCustomUC.xaml.cs
    static FrameworkPropertyMetadata propertymetadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Comes as Default", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(MyCustom_PropertyChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(MyCustom_CoerceValue), false, UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyCustom", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomUC), propertymetadata, new ValidateValueCallback(MyCustom_Validate));

    public string MyCustom
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(MyCustomProperty) as string;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(MyCustomProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

and bind it to a textbox

```
//MyCustomUC.xaml
<UserControl ... x:Name="ucs" ...>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ucs, Path=MyCustom}"></TextBox>
</UserControl>

//MainWindow.xaml
<local:MyCustomUC x:Name="ucust" Grid.Row="0" />
<TextBox x:Name="tbChange" Text="{Binding ElementName=ucust, Path=MyCustom}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

it seems that "MyCustom" will not be changed until Textbox loses focus. How can I make it be changed when the text in Textbox in real time?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbChange" Text="{Binding ElementName=ucust, Path=MyCustom, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. So I found that TextBox will trigger update when lose focus by default.